# End of statement expected in vb net

Tags: sql, vb.net, insert

I'm using VB 2008 express edition and I'm passing four textbox values to the db. The dim statment is written outside the function inside the public class.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class AddRecord
    Dim insertQuery As String
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Server= DESKTOP-STMQUHM; Database = HospitalDB; Intergrated Security= true")

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click   
        insertQuery="insert into Patient_details(NAME,HOUSENAME,DISTRICT,DISEASE)VALUES('"& RichTextBox1.Text& "','" & RichTextBox2.Text& "','" & RichTextBox3.Text& "',"& RichTextBox8.Text& ")",connection               //error line

        ExecuteQuery(insertQuery)

        MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted")
```

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wJLg.png)

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npZkj.png)

Comment: Fix the formatting (prefix code w/ 4 spaces). Also, explain in your post what isn't working, what you need help with.

Comment: Many people think they are doing the right thing by creating a class or something that executes SQL statements but they are not if it requires them to build SQL using string concatenation.  That is almost certainly the root of your issue.  Learn to use parameters and issue like this will likely go away.  That said, I'm guessing what the issue might be because you haven't actually explained it to us.

Comment: [Beware of little bobby tables.](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: What is the connection variable doing at the end of the line that errors? insertQuery is a string; it cannot have a connection flapping in the breeze after the final quotation mark. You may be confusing this with the overload of the Command object constructor that takes an SQL statement and a connection as arguments.

Comment: It worked after I introduced parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little closer to what you want to do. Comments and explanations in-line.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
        'The Using block will close and dispose of your connection
        Using connection As New SqlConnection("Server= DESKTOP-STMQUHM; Database = HospitalDB; Intergrated Security= true")
            'Parameters greatly simplifies the query eliminating quotation errors
            Dim insertQuery = "insert into Patient_details(NAME,HOUSENAME,DISTRICT,DISEASE)VALUES(@Name, @HouseName, @District, @Disease)"
            Dim com As New SqlCommand(insertQuery, connection)
            'Why are you using RichTextBoxes instead of TextBoxes?
            com.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = RichTextBox1.Text
            com.Parameters.Add("@HouseName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = RichTextBox2.Text
            com.Parameters.Add("@District", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = RichTextBox3.Text
            com.Parameters.Add("@Disease", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = RichTextBox4.Text
            Try
                connection.Open()
                com.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted")
                'You will probably want to catch and handled more detailed exceptions
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked after I changed the code. You saved me and may god bless you

Comment: How about a `Using` statement for `SqlCommand`?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Well, I used to do that but was corrected. Command can simply fall out of scope. It does have a Dispose method. Maybe I should start doing it again?